# Commit a file in Github in AWS CodePipeline

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-codepipeline

I'm creating a AWS CodePipeline with the following phases:

1. Source: Get code from Github when some change occurs in the staging branch.
2. Build:Read the buildspec.yml to execute "mvn clean package", docker build and docker push.
3. Deploy: Deploy to ECS Cluster

Now I need to create a 4 phase (AfterDeploy Phase) that should commit some files in github. So, after all these phases completed with success, the **AfterDeploy Phase** should commit some files generated by Build phase in github.

Any idea how can I do it?

Comment: You can use another  CodeBuild action to do that.

Comment: Do you have a example using a buildspec file ? Should I have 2 buildspec files, because I have 2 build phases ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Should I have 2 buildspec files, because I have 2 build phases ?

Yes, you can do this. For example, you can have primary `buildspec.yml` for your first build, and secondary `buildspec_postdeploy.yml` for the second build stage.

How to use multiple `buildspec` files is documented at:

- [Buildspec file name and storage location](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/codebuild/latest/userguide/build-spec-ref.html#build-spec-ref-name-storage)

I don't have an example to share, but it would just execute any git commint and git push commands that are needed. Its exact structure is very use-case specific, thus it is difficult to speculate on it.

`https://docs.aws.amazon.com/codebuild/latest/userguide/build-spec-ref.html#build-spec-ref-name-storage`

Comment: @userdevexp No problem. Hopefully it will work out :-)